# Solvability of elliptic PDE with Neumann boundary condition

Tags: partial-differential-equations, boundary-value-problem, elliptic-operators

I'm trying to better understand the theory of second-order elliptic PDEs on a smooth compact region $\Omega \in \mathbb{R}^N$ with boundary conditions.  For the Dirichlet case, there seems to be a rich literature on criteria for existence of a solution, culminating in a Fredholm alternative for the system

\begin{align}
Lu - \lambda u &= f \qquad \text{in } \Omega \\
u &= 0 \qquad \text{on } \partial \Omega
\end{align}
where $L$ is a second-order elliptic differential operator and $f$ is smooth.  This system is well-posed and has a (unique) solution $u$ for all $f$ if $\lambda$ is not an eigenvalue of $L$.  If $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $L$, then the system has a solution if and only if $f$ is orthogonal to all eigenfunctions of $L$ with eigenvalue $\lambda$.  See e.g. Sec. 6.2.3 in Evans (2nd ed., 2010).

I am interested in the analogous Neumann system:
\begin{align}
Lu - \lambda u &= f \qquad \text{in } \Omega \\
\hat{n} \cdot \nabla u &= g \qquad \text{on } \partial \Omega
\end{align}
where $\hat{n}$ is the unit normal perpendicular to the boundary and $f,g$ are smooth.  I have found statements in some special cases.  For example if $L = - \nabla^2$, $\lambda = 0$ then this system has a solution if and only if

\begin{equation}
\int_\Omega f = \int_{\partial \Omega} g
\end{equation}

but I don't see a way to generalize easily.

Is there some general-purpose theorem for existence of a solution to this system?  Does a weak solution to this system have any guaranteed interior regularity properties?  I am most interested in the case $L = -\nabla^2$, $\lambda \neq 0$, so I would be satisfied with a result that applies only to this case.

Comment: A direct computation (assuming $L := \nabla^{2}$) shows that the value of $\lambda$ has no impact on the necessary solvability condition, which is again that $$\int_{\Omega} f \ dx = \int_{\partial \Omega} g \ dx$$ Just take the inner product of the system with a function $v$ that satisfies the homogeneous, Neumann adjoint problem 
\begin{align}
(L - \lambda) v &= 0 \\
\hat{n} \cdot \nabla v &= 0
\end{align}
and use [Greens theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green%27s_identities) repeatedly.

Comment: @MatthewCassell Could you please explain how we still have 
$$\int_{\Omega} f =\int_{\partial \Omega} g$$ ? 
I have the bilinear equation as 
$$
\int_{\Omega} \nabla u \nabla v+ \int_{\Omega} u v =\int_{\Omega} f +\int_{\partial \Omega} g \gamma v 
$$ 
where $\gamma v$ is the trace of $v$. For $v=1$, I end up with
$$
\lambda \int_{\Omega} u=\int_{\Omega} f+\int_{\partial \Omega} g
$$.